# Highchart offline export for pdf file not working

Tags: highcharts

I am using the latest High-stock , exporting and offline-exporting java script file for my angular application. When I use the highstock api "exportChartLocal" in my code as "chart.exportChartLocal({type:"application/pdf"});", I can able to download for png,jpeg and svf format.But I am not able to get the pdf format displaying as "file damaged".Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: are you using Highcharts module, or Highcharts plugin? http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/37/highcharts-export-clientside

Comment: No I am using http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export . I am having the seperate button , on clicking I am calling the "chart.exportChartLocal({type:"application/pdf"});" function to export from browser.

Comment: I don't think that client side export have option to export your chart to pdf. I think that in this case you may use plugin I gave you a link to.

Comment: Thanks for the link.I used the Highchart-Client-Export module and tried exporting.In chrome I am getting for png,jpeg,pdf and also svg.But in IE 9 & 10, I am not able to export the jpeg format.The browser goes to idle state and in console I am getting as parser error.